# How to link parent project library from CMake subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I am creating a C++ library with CMake. In the project there is a CMake subdirectory, which builds to an executable and it aims to test the library. The structure of the project can be seen below:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
 |--CMakeLists.txt
 |--src
 |   |--B1.cpp
 |   |--B1.h
 |
 |--test (added as subdirectory)
      |--CMakeLists.txt
      |--test.cpp
```

The project root is a library I would like to link it to the test subdirectory.

```
#PROJECT_ROOT CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(project_root)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
       B1.cpp
       B1.h
       )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

add_subdirectory(test)
```

and this is the CMakeLists.txt file of the test subdirectory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

add_executable(test
        test.cpp
        )

target_link_libraries(test
        project_root       # <------------- Here, I would like to link the created 
                           #                library of the parent project                                          
        )
```

When building the `test` subdirectory, I got undefined reference to the methods coming from the parent project. As far as I know, I only have to link the name of the parent project to the `test` CMake subproject. I also don't know, if I need any `target_include_directories()` referring to the headers of the parent project. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This looks fine.  Are the undefined symbols actually being compiled?

Comment: heads up: if you start using ctest (cmake's testing tool), you will get an error that you can't name a target "test" because it's a reserved name when using ctest.

Comment: note: you don't _need_ to mark the test subdirectory as being its own project (`project(test)` is not necessary (I think)). also note that you are linking the name of the **target** named `project_root` to the test executable- the `add_library(<name> ...)` name is what is being linked. It doesn't need to be the same as the name of the project.